# Baire category theorem for locally compact and Hausdorff proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image]

I understand steps i) and ii) but am confused how iii) is supposed to work. The induction starts at $1$ but $N_0$ is undefined and why does iii) deal with both $U_k$ and $U_{k-1}$? Isn't $U_{k-1}$ already defined?

I also don't get how they got the chain after iii).

Comment: The proof is sloppily written at points. It should have been better proofread (e.g. by Brian)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in (iii). It should say:

> Let $U_k$ be a neighborhood of $x_k$ such that $U_k\subseteq N_k$ (via (ii) above) and $U_k\subseteq D_{k-1}$; this is possible since $D_{k-1}$ is open, and we can take a neighborhood of $x_k$ in $N_k$ and intersect it with $D_{k-1}$ (which is non-empty, since (i) guarantees $x_k\in D_{k-1}$.

There is also an error in the next line: the chain of inclusions should read

$$U_0\supseteq N_1\color{red}\supseteq U_1\supseteq N_2\supseteq U_2\ldots\;.$$

This follows immediately from (ii) and (iii).

There are also a few errors in the final paragraph, not to mention a little sloppiness in the indexing. Since we have a $D_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and we explicitly have a $D_0$ in (i) when $k=1$, the author must be following my preferred convention, according to which $\Bbb N$ is the set of non-negative integers and therefore includes $0$. However, the sets $N_k$ are defined only for $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, so the next sentence should read:

> Each $N_k$ is compact, hence closed by the previous proposition, and for every $k\in\color{red}{\Bbb Z^+}$ we have $\bigcap_{i\le k}N_i=N_k\ne\varnothing$.

The same change has to be made twice more, and in addition a real error has to be fixed in the penultimate sentence:

> Thus, by our earlier proposition, $\bigcap_{i\in\color{red}{\Bbb Z^+}}N_i\ne\varnothing$. Take any $y\in\bigcap_{i\in\color{red}{\Bbb Z^+}}N_i$; then for every $i$, $y\in N_{i+\color{red}2}\subseteq U_{\color{red}{i+1}}\subseteq D_i$, and $y\in N_{\color{red}1}\subseteq U_0=U$.

The last sentence is okay.